# Remap a key press in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an "easy" way to map a keystroke to another key when on a page?

**Background:**

We are using a custom javascript grid for handling keyboard entry in a web application.  Normally, the [enter] key allows the user to move to the next line, and the [tab] key allows the users to move to the right.  The grid handles the keystrokes, and has some rather complicated logic when one is pressed.

Our users are requesting that we map the Plus Key [+] on the numeric keypad to [tab] so that they don't need to use two hands while keying.  This seems logical (the are keying thousands of numbers in a row while holding papers with their other hand), but I can't figure out to do it.

Comment: _"Holding papers with their other hand"_ `head -> desk`.

Comment: @Matt - These are data entry clerks.  They receive faxed forms that they need to key into our system.  It's much easier to keep their place and "blind key" with their finger than any other method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could do something like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 107) { // + key on num keyboard on my keyboard, test your clients to be sure
     e.preventDefault();
     //trigger tab functionality here
  }
});
```

To trigger the tab functionality, i'd use `focus()` called on elements which have `tabindex="0"` set so they fall into the natural taborder of the page and are focusable - if it is formelements they are already focusable and there is no need for the tabindex attribute.

Answer (score 3):

You can trigger a keypress event on an element when the `+` or `-` keys are press on an element by doing this:

```
$("body").keypress(function(e){
    if ( e.which === 43 || e.which === 45 ) {
        $(e.target).trigger({
            type: "keypress",
            which: 13
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This triggers the enter key on both `-` and `+`. You should be able to trigger the tab event too, however it will not cause the default browser behavior of going to the next element.

Comment: An interesting technique to generate a new event to trigger, however why would you create a custom `tab` event separate from the `+` event?

Comment: That just depends on how the grid plugin is written. Generating a tab event would not make sense because more than likely the grid is using tab-index to allow for tabbing between the cells. However, if the grid is listening for an enter keypress, triggering that will cause the grid's keypress handler to fire and move focus to the next cell.

Comment: The ultimate goal is for the `+` key to move you to the next cell. Without knowing how the grid works or how it handles keypresses, we are working in the dark here. For all we know each input is wrapped in a form, and upon pressing `enter` the form gets submitted, or upon pressing `tab` the `blur` event could trigger the form submit and focus the next cell.

Comment: We'd actually prefer this to be a page-level action that we could just apply everywhere and let the browser handle as well, since there is more than 1 data entry screen (the grid is just the most complex).  Any thoughts on whether or not this is possible?

Comment: its going to depend very much on how the grid works. you can capture the + and - keys getting pressed, what you do with them will depend on the grid plugin.